# Не могу клонировать репозиторий с GitHub

Tags: git, github

Не могу клонировать репозиторий через SmartGit, выдал ошибку:
Invalid path: beta/public_html/img/????? glyphicons-halflings.png

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: похоже что в пути есть кириллические символы (там где знаки вопроса).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы на винде? Проблема с путями файлов! Пробуй на linux.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно винда не может создать файлы с знаками ?, > и т.д...

Comment: Остаётся вопрос, откуда там эти ? вообще взялись и какая часть системы сломалась. И когда.

Comment: незнаю откуда... но была уже такая проблема, решил - перешёл на ubuntu.